# How to describe/name all the paths in an undirected graph where every node has no more than two neighbors?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I am modeling a road network as a graph, using GPS data, etc.

A typical fraction of my graph would look like below:

[image]

What I would like is to partition this graph as a list of node sequences, where every red dot would be used to *split* the network, generating a collection of simple polylines, so that every polyline would have a red dot in each endpoint, and no red dot inside the polyline.

I tried to ask some questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711964/finding-consecutive-edges-linking-certain-nodes-in-graph), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690227/finding-connectedness-from-a-list-of-nodes-and-a-list-of-edges)) regarding this problem in StackOverflow, but I'm afraid I'm not using the appropriate terminology.

Comment: Will these red points always be on vertices with degree larger than 2? (As it turns out to be in this picture) Otherwise, your lines with red endpoints might come across a vertex to which there are more than one way to choose.

Comment: @ErikJoensson The description says that the red dots are all vertices of degree larger than $2$. A related ambiguity concern that I have is: should the red dots be *all* vertices of degree larger than $2$? Or should it be a minimal set such that removing them keeps all remaining vertices of degree at most $2$? In the example this ambiguity does not come up, but certainly you can imagine drawing too parallel lines and then connecting one vertex of one with a vertex of the other, with no vertex in between.

Comment: This doesn't refer to such paths or in particular to this process, but [edge contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction) is a related key word. You are, in particular, trying to contract various paths into single edges.

Comment: One way to find the polylines would be as the connected components of the graph resulting from removing all the red nodes.

Comment: @ErikJoensson I didn't have the terminology when I first wrote the question, but yes, the red dots are _by definition_ all the nodes with degree larger than 2.

Comment: @Ian the direct connection of two "red dots" is an interesting _edge case_ (pun intended), because I am not sure what would be the best partitioning: keep the red dots on their polylines (thus creating _n_ references to it, with _n_ equal to the red dot degree), or perform an hierarchical partitioning, where each found path's endpoints would be connected to a red dot, but would not contain it.

Comment: @Rahul, I guess you are right, but that leaves the problem of knowing the paths from a given red node to some other red node (a sequence of paths)

Comment: By the way, this link was a treasure to me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory

Comment: What is your question, exactly? You want the graph theoretical term for the collection of such paths?

Comment: @Szmagpie Yes, exactely. I want to go to StackOverflow and ask a question like "Algorithm to find the <name of these paths> in Python", or "What are the commands to find <name of these paths> using `networkx` library`. I don't know how to _name_ them (although I think the solution itself would be easy for the initiated) but I suspect that "all paths whose endpoints are are of degree 1 or degree more than 2, and the other points are of degree 2". Or something equivalent.